# Laravel Homestead "No input file specified"

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I installed Laravel with Homestead and tried to start a project that I created. Therefore I adjusted the Homestead.yaml to:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/Development/Source/MFServer/
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: local.medifaktor
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/MFServer/public
```

The path is existing but still I get this error message. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Have you run homestead provision since editing the yaml? Does your host file have that url associated with the correct ip address?

Comment: yep...no change

Comment: yep, 192.168.10.10 local.medifaktor

Comment: Try running running the command `vagrant provision`.

Comment: tried that, but not working. Still the same message, but no other error

Comment: I checked the folder within the virtual machine which is existing and available

Comment: I think you should map just the Source folder to Code instead of the MFServer within

Comment: Try this `$ serve local.medifaktor /home/vagrant/Code/MFServer/public`

Answer (score 0):

I think this only works when you need to reload the file and there is no other problems.

From Jesús' site: http://www.jesusamieiro.com/no-input-file-specified-using-homestead/

“No input file specified” using Homestead - Posted on 02/06/2016

If you see the message “No input file specified” in the browser (using Homestead as development VM machine), one possible problem is that Homestead doesn’t load the parameters from the config file Homestead.yaml

Try to provision the VM another time, running

```
$ vagrant reload --provision
```